# How to fully understand the first three chapters of Phenomenology of Spirit?

Tags: hegel, phenomenology

I read The Phenomenology of Spirit like 10 years ago, but I felt like it was very vague and abstract. Hegel seemed to have been describing the development of human thought with respect to the absolute truth, but I didn't know if it was a historical development, the natural human development of the mind from an individual perspective or whatnot, and the whole process seemed to be very vague and too abstract to me.

What would you recommend someone to do to fully understand it? I remember there was a dictionary for the book, which was as thick as the book itself and I thought it was ridiculous. How did people like Marx came to understand the book? Did they just understand it by reading it? I feel it's impossible to understand the book fully by merely reading it.

Comment: Marx had the advantage of attending lectures, and mingling with, Hegel's students in person (Gans, Feuerbach, Bauer), and many attest that Hegel himself was a spellbinding lecturer (indeed, it explains how he managed to inspire so many people given the way his works are written). Don't worry, nobody knows precisely what Hegel has in mind there, hence anyone can read in what suits them best (as did Marx), which has its own benefits. If you want an aid you can peruse a commentary, e.g. Findlay's, Siep's or Stern's, free electronic versions of each come up upon googling.

Comment: "Mill opined that a sustained dose of Hegelian prose might addle the brain irreversibly..." https://ndpr.nd.edu/news/the-phenomenology-of-spirit/

Comment: @conifold  `many attest that Hegel himself was a spellbinding lecturer` <--  this seems to be the opposite of what the editors of the lecture series (e.g. Hodgson's 2006 and 2007 introductions to Hegel's Lectures on the Philosophy of Religion). Do you have citation for Hegel being a good lecturer?

Comment: @repomonster my sense as a Hegel scholar is that Marx does not have a good grasp of Hegel. There's (and I speak glibly) an inverse fame rule: the more famous the commentator is independently the more likely the reading is not good or faithful.

Comment: Robert C. Solomon authored *In the Spirit of Hegel*, which is a study of Phenomenology of Spirit.

Comment: More practical items: Q. Lauer https://www.amazon.com/Reading-Hegels-Phenomenology-Spirit/dp/0823213552 Findlay (not a Marxist as far as I know) but commentary on the Phenomenology https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/hegel/help/findlay.htm

Comment: @virmaior See Löwith From Hegel to Nietzsche, he quotes Bauer, as I recall.

Comment: @Conifold thanks. I don't really have anything riding on whether he's a good lecturer or not but Hodgson states, "Hegel was by no means an eloquent lecturer, and it must be assumed that his delivery was particularly halting in those lectures he gave from manuscripts ... he spoke slowly and repetitiously, with much pausing to clear his throat, to find his place as he thumbed through sheets, and to express his thoughts in the right words" (Hodgson, 2007, Editor's Introduction to Vol 1 of Lectures on the Philosophy of Religion).

Comment: Reference in after "lecturer" is to *Hegel in Berichten seiner Zeitgenossen* (Hamburg, 1970) with a stack of page references.

Comment: Greg Sadler has super detailed videos on youtube which go through PoS line by line. When I read it a few years ago (before these existed) I found JM Bernstein's lecture, which are also online in audio, v helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the first three chapters of The Phenomenology of Spirit, it is important to keep in mind that Hegel is primarily concerned with the development of human thought. This development is not simply a historical or chronological process, but rather a dialectical one. In other words, it is a process in which each stage emerges out of and negates the previous one.

The first chapter, "Sense-Certainty," deals with our most immediate and basic form of knowledge, which is based on the senses. This form of knowledge is limited, because it is only concerned with the particular and the here and now. It cannot grasp concepts or universals.

The second chapter, "Perception," deals with a more sophisticated form of knowledge, in which we not only take account of the particular objects around us, but also begin to see them in relation to one another and to universals. This form of knowledge is still limited, because it is based on the external world of appearances.

The third chapter, "Force and the Understanding," introduces us to the world of thought, where we move beyond the limitations of sense-certainty and perception. In this chapter, Hegel discusses the concept of "force" (or "strength"), which he sees as the fundamental principle underlying all reality. He also introduces the idea of "the understanding," which is our capacity to reason.

The first three chapters of The Phenomenology of Spirit are difficult, but they are essential to understanding Hegel's thought. By working through these chapters carefully, we can begin to see how human thought develops and how it is dialectically related to the absolute truth.